# Limit the number of .filter result list - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to limit the no. of filter list. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".table tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

So, when i type 'Food' in search-box all 13 table rows containing food word appears, and rest will hide.

But i am trying to show only first 5 rows, rather than all 13 rows.
Appreciate, if Anyone have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Array.slice

```
$(".table tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
}).slice(5).remove();
```

`Slice(index)` returns all elements in the array from index till the last element. In this case being all the elements, calling remove() on those elements will delete them and thus only displaying the first 5 elements.
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: I applied but no effect.